# I want to post in database in WP by Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a form to add data in table using plugin in wordpress but when i enters submitt button it shows nothing and no data add in table where i doing mistake?? plz anybody help me.
My code for insert data is here...

```
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  Name
  <input type="text" name="name" /> </br>
  Website 
    <input type="text" name="website" /> </br>
    Description
    <input type="text" name="description" /> </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
     </form>
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query($structure);
    $wpdb->query="insert into ".PRO_TABLE_PREFIX."tutorial ( name, website, description )
    values('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['website']}','{$_POST['description']}')";
    if (is_object($wpdb) && is_a($wpdb, 'wpdb')) {
    if (!$wpdb->insert('.PRO_TABLE_PREFIX.tutorial',
    array(
                            'name'=>$_POST[name]
                            ,'website'=>$_POST[website]
                            ,'description'=>$_POST[description]
                ))) exit; 
                } 
else {echo 'Form Submitted';}
?>
```

Comment: Add `$wpdb->show_errors();` just after `global $wpdb;` and you'll see what your problem is.

Comment: Multipost: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75250/i-want-to-post-in-database-in-wp-by-plugin

Answer (score 1):

A blank page usually means an internal 50x error, normally caused by PHP or your web hosting software (which is likely Apache).

```
$wpdb->query="insert into ".PRO_TABLE_PREFIX."tutorial ( name, website, description )
    values('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['website']}','{$_POST['description']}')";
```

`$wpdb->query=` is not valid. The code should read :

```
 $wpdb->query("insert into ".PRO_TABLE_PREFIX."tutorial ( name, website, description )
values('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['website']}','{$_POST['description']}')");
```

because $wpdb->query is a function, not a variable.

**Update:** (More in-depth)

First, let me start by linking to the [wpdb documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). For your purpose, you'll want to do this:

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix."my_table";
```

Note: When typing in the table name, don't include the "wp_" prefix. The "wp_" prefix can be changed by a number of things, but it will always be stored in `$wpdb->prefix`, so always use this instead of typing the default prefix.

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert($table,array(
    "name" => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']),
    "website" => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['website']),
    "description" => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description'])
));
```

That will enter the record into your database. mysql_real_escape_string is important to protect yourself against [MYSQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). That's about all there is to it.

**Update 2:** (response to next comment)

Then you need to have PHP check to see if the form is submitted. You could simply add `if(isset($_POST)){}`, but I personally don't like doing that because if another form submitted to this page via post, the database would still update.

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST[PLUGIN_PREFIX.'submit'])){ 

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.PLUGIN_PREFIX."my_table";

    // $wpdb->insert will return true or false based on if the query was successful.
    $success = $wpdb->insert($table,array(
        "name" => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[PLUGIN_PREFIX.'name']),
        "website" => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[PLUGIN_PREFIX.'website']),
        "description" => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[PLUGIN_PREFIX.'description'])
    ));

    if($success){
        $display = '<div class="'.PLUGIN_PREFIX.'submit_success">
            Your data has been saved.
        </div>';
    }else{
        $display = '<div class="'.PLUGIN_PREFIX;.'submit_fail">
            Your data failed to save. Please try again.
        </div>';
    }
}

$display .= '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="'.PLUGIN_PREFIX.'name" /> </br>

    <label for="website">Website</label> 
    <input id="website" type="text" name="'.PLUGIN_PREFIX.'website" /> </br>

    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <input id="description" type="text" name="'.PLUGIN_PREFIX.'description" /> </br>

    <input type="hidden" name="'.PLUGIN_PREFIX.'submit" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>';

return $display;
```

A few things I added that seem to be part of good plugin development:

- One of the first lines of the first file in your plugin should have a line similar to `define('PLUGIN_PREFIX', 'plugin_name_');`. Use the prefix before anything that may conflict with other plugins.
- `<label>` tags are very important. if the label's "for" matches an input's "id", clicking the label will select that input.
- Returning a variable holding your HTML is the proper way to display plugins. If you have other content on that page above the plugin and you just echo the form, the form will appear above everything else, regardless of the position of the shortcode.

Comment: I'll update my answer to go a little more in depth. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: This code adding data automatically when i refresh the webpage how to get rid of?